# problemas con Git entre multiples ramas

Tags: git, git-push

Hace poco el dev me dijo que yo había subido archivos demás que los que debía subir, es decír subi las clases que debía trabajar y se fueron otras pero nunca les di **add** y es extraño

Tengo la siguiente estructura:

**Rama1, MiRama y master**

Rama1 tiene copia de master.

MiRama tiene copia de Rama1

Siempre he estado trabajando en MiRama desarrollando mi codigo...

Ahora me podrían indicar como sería la estructura de codigo para enviar mi codigo de MiRama a Rama1... Que sea con git pull y git push para ver en que fallo (tener en cuenta que aveces suben codigo a master y hay que hacerle pull)

Answer (score 0):

Depende de los estándares de tu empresa, La cual según lo que entiendo es que no se ha realizado un Merge "MiRama" Al master (no debería ser, ya que debe pasar por un control de calidad).

Así mismo entendí que algunas ramas se encuentra protegido (es lo ideal), por lo tanto debes solicitar un "Pull Request".

Para realizar un Merge, primero que nada debes solicitar un Pull Request de "MiRama" a "Rama1"

```
git add .
git commit -m "Mis cambios"
git push origin MiRama
```

Posteriormente el software o plataforma que utilizas para manejar tu control de versiones (Como por ejemplo GitLab, GitHub, entre otro más...), se debe realizar un Pull Request la cual solicitas realizar un Merge de: "MiRama" a "Rama1", asignando al usuario de control de calidad correspondiente. (**Ojo** en este paso puede existir conflictos, si la hay te recomiendo que la resuelvas)

Luego debes esperar a que dicho usuario te acepte los cambios y realice el Merge de tu rama a Rama1, en caso que el usuario te lo rechace, debe solicitar información o motivo de rechazo, para que lo mejores y vuelvas a realizar otro pull request.

Finalmente el encargado de Rama1, debe solicitar un pull request para que se incluya los cambios respectivo a la rama Master.